# Cant Build c# asp.net mvc application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

When I try to build the application i get:

```
Error   1   Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' -- 'Index not found.' NHMDLive.Models
```

I cant figure out what the problem might be. I have checked the mscorlib.dll and did a checksum and it is not corrupted. Must be something else.

Comment: I got the same error with VS 2013 - `Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' -- 'Unknown error (8007000e)'`. Later my exe being debugged crashed with `low memory` error. Though I got this error while trying to debug and not building it. Also you have something additional `Index not found` thingy.

Answer (score 2):

you can't code for the version 4 of dotnet with vs 2008.

You will have either to upgrade to VS 2010, or use 3.5 or less version of assemblies

Comment: Im sorry about the tag I am using VS 2010

Comment: no pb. If you create a new blank project from scratch and if you do no modification... does it compiles ?

Comment: No i get the same message. I have also tried repair installing .net 4. If i try to compile the same blank project under 3.5 it compiles just fine.

Comment: try to reinstall also VS 2010... but it's only a bet.